# Difference between artifacts and artifacts.new in truffle

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

What is the difference between below two objects in the truffle test file:

1. `const simpleStorage = artifacts.require('SimpleStorage');`
2. `const instance = await simpleStorage.new({from: accounts[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

`simpleStorage` is an instance of your solidity contract

`instance` is an instance of `web3.eth.Contract` which is connected to the blockchain.

A way to put it on MVC terms is that `simpleStorage` is a module while instance ins your ORM with the `simpleStorage` module loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The naming might be a little confusing. It can be changed a little to make it more readable:

The first line is creating a *Class*.

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require('SimpleStorage');
```

The second is deploying an *instance* of the *Class* (code was missing `await`).

```
const instance = await SimpleStorage.new({from: accounts[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question is what is how both objects are different in the case of the data they are holding. What does simpleStorage and instance holds?

Comment: @FLASH From an OOP perspective SimpleStorage is a class, and instance is an object. SimpleStorage contains the contract ABI, it is used to deploy new instances or access already deployed instances from an address. The instance references an already deployed contract, it is used to make queries to the contract and execute transactions that will modify the contract storage.